# activeadmin-mongoid: How to filter on id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, activeadmin

This doesn't work:

```
filter :name, :as => :string
```

Because mongoid ids are not strings, you can't filter on the ids as a string.  Is there a nice way to filter on the ids by creating a custom filter type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a way - I'm not sure exactly why it works yet, but:

```
filter :device_id, :as => :numeric
```

does the trick.